# Apache shiro blocks p:imageCropper primefaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2, shiro, glassfish-4

I'm using primefacess-5.1 and apache shiro 1.2.2 with pax-shiro 0.1.0 overlay. Everything stand on Glassfish 4.0 . My problem is that when I comment all fragment below in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

ImageCropper works fine but shiro doesn't. When I uncomment code above shiro works fine but when I press button crop in p:imageCropper I get error 500 whitch you can see below.

```
            [2014-12-06T18:19:27.913+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1417886367913] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.imagecropper.ImageCropperRenderer.getConvertedValue(ImageCropperRenderer.java:141)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

My JSF form is below

```
<h:body>

<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:imageCropper id="ic"  value="#{cropperView.croppedImage}" image="http://rg-rgb-szkola:8080/dpsmvn-web/admin/images/tmp/portret_wup.jpg" initialCoords="225,75,300,125"/>
        <p:graphicImage alt="po wykadrowaniu" id="cropped" rendered="#{cropperView.photocomlete==1?true:false}" library="images"  name="twarze/pracownicy/#{cropperView.newImageName}.jpg" /> 
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Crop" action="#{cropperView.crop}"   update="msgs ic cropped" icon="ui-icon-scissors" ajax="false"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Zapisz" action="#{cropperView.saveImage()}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>

        </h:body>
```

My shiro config is below

```
[main]  

authc.successUrl = /witamy.xhtml
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.xhtml
ssl.enabled = false

[urls]

/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/ = anon
/images/tla/sloneczniki.jpg = anon
/images/tla/liscie-tlo.jpg = anon
/index.xhtml = anon
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout.xhtml = logout

/witamy.xhtml = authc


/pielegniarka/** = authc, roles[adminpielegniarka]
/admin/** = authc, roles[root]

/** = authc
```

Code reponsible for variable ImageCropper imagecropper is below and is inside CDI bean with @SessionScoped. I can say also that reason of error is NULL value of this variable. I suppose that shiro doesn't recognized mime-type of this variable. I can say that because on start my work with this component i got warning WARNING: JSF1091

```
private CroppedImage croppedImage;

public CroppedImage getCroppedImage() {
    return croppedImage;
}

public void setCroppedImage(CroppedImage croppedImage) {
    this.croppedImage = croppedImage;
}
```

My question is how to synchronize apache shiro with p:imageCropper primefaces component ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution proved to be very simple. I simply add line 
**/admin/cropprofile.xhtml = authc** to my shiro.ini
This is site with p:imageCropper component and authorisated permissions 
To be sure that everything will be works I also add line 
/resources/** = anon but I think it's no needed
So i can say that problem i SOLVED !!! :)
All my shiro.ini file is below

```
[main]

authc.successUrl = /witamy.xhtml
authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.xhtml
ssl.enabled = false

[urls]

/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/resources/** = anon
/ = anon
/images/tla/sloneczniki.jpg = anon
/images/tla/liscie-tlo.jpg = anon
/admin/cropprofile.xhtml = authc
/index.xhtml = anon
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout.xhtml = logout

/witamy.xhtml = authc

/pielegniarka/** = authc, roles[adminpielegniarka]
/admin/** = authc, roles[root]

/** = authc
```